# Can't add file permissions need to relocate SQL Server 2012 files to separate drive

Tags: sql-server-2012, file-permissions

After installing a new SQL Server 2012 Instance, I wish to move the database files to a separate drive.  When I perform File->Properties on the target location and then click Security->Edit->Add->Advanced, select Location=MachineName, and click find, I see only the form related to analysis services:

```
SQLServerMSASUser$MachineName$InstanceName
```

I think the permission I really need is this one which I can see exists in the default C: drive location:

```
MSSQL$InstanceName
```

When I attempt to just enter it directly it is unrecognized.  If I set the directory to "Everyone" and then move the database there (using a restore) it works and shows the above permission on the mdf file.  How can I set that permission on the parent directory when it isn't showing up as an available entry in the list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the install logs, the account MSSQL$*InstanceName* is shorthand for:

NT Service\MSSQL$*InstanceName*

which *can* be entered directly.  I still don't know why these don't show up in the list though.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the relevant MSDN article: [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219062.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! This article helped me realize I had to use NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER instead of MSSQLSERVER and give Full Control (not just write)

Comment: Can you summarize the important parts of that page here, in your answer, in case that link ever dies?

Answer (score 6):

Here's two much easier ways if you can't determine the correct user permissions required (provided you have admin permissions)...

### Method 1 - Disk replacement
*(i.e. drive letter of SQL Server database files will ultimately be the same)*

Especially useful if you are replacing a secondary hard drive where the SQL Server database files reside (e.g. for a bigger one).  Right-click the database(s) in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), Tasks, Take offline.

Then simply copy the files and preserve their ownership:

- go to a command prompt (if on [Windows NT 6.x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_6#Releases), e.g. Vista / 7 /
  2008, remember to right click on Command Prompt and Run as
  administrator)
- [then use](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323007):

  ```
  xcopy D:\path\sql1 E:\path\sql2 /E /F /I /V /K /O /X
  ```

where:

- `/E` - copy directories and subdirectories, including empty ones
- `/F` - displays full source and destination files when copying
- `/I` - if destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes destination is a directory
- `/V` - verifies each new file
- `/K` - preserves attributes, including read-only
- `/O` - copy file ownership and ACL permissions
- `/X` - copy file audit settings (implies `/O`)

you may also want, depending on what files you are migrating:

- `/C` - continues copying even if errors occur
- `/G` - allows copying of encrypted files to a location that does not support encryption
- `/H` - copies hidden and system files

Replace the drive and make sure the drive letter is the same as before. Finally right-click the databases in SSMS, Tasks, Bring online.

### Method 2 - Moving the files to another disk or partition 
*(i.e. drive letter of SQL Server database files will change)*

Useful when you want to free up space on a drive/partition (such as on your precious SSD disk so you can put the files on a secondary standard platter disk!).

Right-click the database(s) you want to move in SSMS, Tasks, Detach.  Navigate to the files, which are typically at something like `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` and called `MyDatabase.mdf` and multiple copies of `MyDatabase_1.ndf`.  Copy them to the new location (don't worry about their permissions).

Then [open SSMS as an administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178536/create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5failed-to-retrieve-text-for-thi) otherwise you will end up with a `CREATE FILE` error with something like `Access is denied` in the next step.

Right-click databases, Attach, Add, browse to the newly located `MyDatabase.mdf`.

Voilà!  If you right-click the files and check their permissions before and after attaching in SSMS you'll notice that the permissions have been magically corrected!

Comment: Forgot you could simply stick it in admin mode!

Comment: Thanks - Method 2 worked great. I should point out that his does require SSMS to be installed on the server.