# in Ubuntu CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, access-denied

i followed this article [sqlshack link](https://www.sqlshack.com/change-default-database-file-and-backup-paths-in-sql-server-on-linux/) to change the database file default location.
i completed all the steps, but after when i'm trying to create DB i encounder below error. i also tried this [stackoverlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178536/create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5failed-to-retrieve-text-for-thi) but negative response

error :

`CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file '/home/user/Templates/sampletable.mdf'.`

how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I very much doubt that the `mssql` user or group has access to user's home directory. Place the file in a location that the account has access to.

Comment: Are you sure that you followed all of the steps in the SQLShack tutorial? The error message suggests that you didn't execute the `chown` and `chrgrp` commands on the `/home/user/Templates` directory that you created to store the database files. Check that directory (and the files within it) are owned by `mssql:mssql` or whichever account and group your SQL Server for Linux instance executes under.